# iOS 11 HTTPS network request failure with self-signed cert

Tags: ssl, https, ios11, self-signed

For testing purpose, The project uses a self-signed cert, loaded as a bundle resource for network requests.

It works good on **Xcode8 + iOS10** devices and simulators.

On **Xcode9 and iOS 11**, however, prompts with error as:

```
----------------
<APIClient.swift> call [#77]
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1c0111f70>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x1070fb600) s: *.ABC i:ABC>",
    "<cert(0x1070fce00) s:ABC i: 2048 offline root>",
    "<cert(0x1070fd600) s: 2048 offline root i: 2048 offline root>"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x1c465e180 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x1c0111f70>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x1070fb600) s: *.ABC i:ABC>",
    "<cert(0x1070fce00) s:ABC i: 2048 offline root>",
    "<cert(0x1070fd600) s: 2048 offline root i: 2048 offline root>"
)}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:/
----------------
```

It can be resolved by adding:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I wonder if it is a simulator bug, or the security policy is changed, like self-signed cert is totally prohibited on iOS 11?
If yes, is there a link/documentation reference?